# Magento 1.9 IWD OPC update removes credit card info on changing shipping fields

Tags: magento, onepage-checkout

I am using IWD OPC extension for my magento 1.9 website.
After adding credit card info on OPC page when user changes shipping address or email or shipping method etc It updates page that is fine but it removes added credit card info.
Is there any way I can preserve credit card info for user.Means keep credit card info in form when page is updated.
Please help.Thanks in advance/

Answer (score 1):

Its always updated when you change any previous element in the form. However I noticed the dates and the card type are persisted but not the card number and cvv number which seems odd.

As a work around you can save the card number and cvv number to the Magento session object within the controllers/jsonController.php savePaymentAction() method, then in your payment form cc.phtml grab the session object and populate the card number and cvv number directly into the form.

There is possibly a better fix for this. But for expediency I had to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Comment

```
<block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" [...] </block>
```

in [www_name]/app/design/frontend/[themename]/default/layout/onestepcheckout.xml